# bash script to run in 5 minutes

Tags: bash, timed

I just want a bash script to run 5 minutes after it's called.  What am I doing wrong?

I have the command:

```
/path/to/my/script | at now + 5 min
```

And yet the script runs right away every time.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are executing the script immediately and sending its output into `at`. You need to send the name of the script itself into `at`:

```
echo /path/to/my/script | at now + 5 min
```

Answer (score 33):

how about:

```
sleep 300 && /path/to/my/script
```

Comment: Yeah, this question didn't really need `at`. I'd suggest you use `&&` instead of `;`, so it can be cancelled.

Comment: at is more graceful imo as it does not hang a process.

Comment: yep, I use this one for shutdown `sleep 300 && shutdown -h now`

Comment: using seep for shutdown makes no sense because shutdown itself has a convenient timer integrated `shutdown -P +5`

Answer (score 7):

```
at -f /path/to/my/script -t now +5 minutes
```

This should work as far as scheduling a script to run at a specific time. For any more information on the "`at`" command try [linuxmanpages.com](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/at.1.php). I may be wrong thought ( currently not at a linux system to test ).

Good luck anyways

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're running the script and piping the output to the `at` command.  What you need to do is run the `at` command with the path to your script as a parameter.  I'm not sure of the syntax, but `at -h` or `man at` should help.

Answer (score 1):

Commands are evaluated left to right, so first your script gets executed, the output of it will be piped to the at command, this is normal behaviour. Have look at at the [at man pages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

`sys.scheduled_run /path/to/my/script 5`

main function

```
function sys.scheduled_run(){
    local PATH_TO_ACTION MINS SLEEPTIME
    PATH_TO_ACTION=$1
    MINS=$2
    SLEEPTIME=$(($MINS * 60))
    echo "Sleeping for $MINS minute ($SLEEPTIME seconds) and then running $PATH_TO_ACTION"
    ui.countdown $SLEEPTIME
    $PATH_TO_ACTION
    echo "Done"
    if [ "REPEAT" == "$3" ] 
    then
        echo "Going for Repeat"
        sys.scheduled_run "$@"
    fi
}
```

countdown function

```
function ui.countdown(){ #USAGE ui.countdown 60 countdown for 60 seconds
        local SECONDS=$1
        local START=$(date +%s)
        local END=$((START + SECONDS))
        local CUR=$START
        while [[ $CUR -lt $END ]]
        do
                CUR=$(date +%s)
                LEFT=$((END-CUR))

                printf "\r%02d:%02d:%02d" \
                        $((LEFT/3600)) $(( (LEFT/60)%60)) $((LEFT%60))

                sleep 1
        done
        echo "        "
}
```